# returning value to main C#

Tags: c#

I'll start by saying that i am no beginner in C# but not very much more and need help returning value to main. Or rather tell me what is the "correct" way.

I want to return a fail value (simply -1) from the application, in case of any exception and ending up in a catch. In that case passing info to main to return -1.

The way I solved it was by just adding a static global variable mainReturnValue (to be able to access it from main), and setting its value to -1 in the catches.

Is that a correct way of doing it, based on my current code?

If anyone is wondering the applications is executed without user interaction and that's why I need to catch the exit state. The form/GUI just displays info about the progress, in case it's started manually.

```
namespace ApplicationName
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Form1.
/// </summary>
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{ ...

static int mainReturnValue = 0; //the return var

static int Main(string[] args) 
{
    Application.Run(new Form1(args));

    return mainReturnValue; //returning 0 or -1 before exit
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
    the code..in turn also calling some sub functions such as DoExportData...and I want to be able to return the value to main from any function...
}

private int DoExportData(DataRow dr, string cmdText)
{
    try { ... } 
    catch
    { mainReturnValue = -1; }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You could do this:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1(args);
    Application.Run(form1);
    return form1.Result;
}
```

and then define a property on your `Form1` class, whose value you can set after the `DoExportData` method executes. For example:

```
public int Result { get; private set; }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
    Result = DoExportData(...);
}

private int DoExportData(DataRow dr, string cmdText)
{
    try 
    {
        ...
        return 0;
    } 
    catch
    { 
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this can work. You only get to the line following `Application.Run` by closing `form1`. By then `form1.Result` does not exist anymore

Comment: @EMett After `Application.Run()` has finished the form won't be displayed anymore, but the object referenced by `form1` still exists.

Answer (score 2):

[How to: Get and Set the Application Exit Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350179(v=vs.100).aspx)  from MSDN.

By the way, an exit code of `0` indicates success, while anything `> 0` indicates an error.

Answer (score 1):

I would add **also** something like this

```
  AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
  currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CrashHandler);


  static void CrashHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) {
     mainReturnValue = -1;
  }
```

Just to be sure that even unhandled exceptions are "handled" by your application in a way you want, cause I presume your app is not only about one WindowsForm.